# Way to return a list from DAC Layer without using IEnumerable<SelectListItem> of System.Web.Mvc at that layer to bind MVC @Html.DropdownListFor()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Do there is any way by which we can return a list from DAC Layer without using IEnumerable of System.Web.Mvc at DAC Layer to bind MVC @Html.DropdownListFor() for strongly types view in mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you just bind the list on the view itself? If your model contains a property of type IEnumerable called Roles then on your view you can do:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleId, new SelectList(Model.Roles, "YourDataValueFieldName", "YourDataTextFieldName"))
```

In other words you can pass with your model any object that satisfies the IEnumerable interface and bind it to the SelectList on the view itself.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was skipping.

Answer (score 1):

Simple - use view models and fill selectlist in controller

Model

```
public class CreateUserViewModel 
{
    public int RoleId { get; set;} 
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RolesSelectList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    CreateUserViewModel model = new CreateUserViewModel();
    model.RolesSelectList = DAC.GetRoles().Select(role => new SelectListItem() { Text = Role.Name, Value = Role.RoleId.ToString() });
    return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@model CreateUserViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleId, Model.RolesSelectList);
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting But I have different requirement, AS I am not using View models in my presentation layer, I am using Extended entity partial classes for creating models that will be used in view and I want to write a code to return a List FROM DAC Layer(Which does not contains System.Web.Mvc reference and hence no IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) so which type of list i need to return from there so that i will be easily bind a dropdown in view